# Custom reference contributor is not being called while running tests for Intellij Platform plugin

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Intellij Platform (actually for PhpStorm).

My plugin is providing references within string literal expressions in PHP language.
I created a reference contributor and a few reference provider classes.
My plugin works perfectly when I run it within PhpStorm.

My plugin becomes bigger, so I decided to write a few tests for it.
I created an unit test using IntelliJ IDEA "Create test" action and choosed JUnit 3.
When I run test (see code below), the class `MyPsiReferenceContributor` is not being accessed at all, and test expectedly fails ("Test failed").
`parent.getReferences()` returns an empty array (`parent` is an instance of StringLiteralExpressionImpl).

Is seems that `MyPsiReferenceContributor` is not being registered in test environment.

**What should I do to make my reference contributor available within tests?**

I used this project https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin as example,
but my plugin is not using Gradle as theirs does.

This is how I registered my reference contributor in `plugin.xml`:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <psi.referenceContributor implementation="com.zenden2k.MyFrameworkIntegration.MyPsiReferenceContributor"/>
</extensions>
```

This is my reference contributor:

```
public class MyPsiReferenceContributor extends PsiReferenceContributor {
    // This is not being called while running tests! :(
    @Override
    public void registerReferenceProviders(PsiReferenceRegistrar registrar) {
        MyPsiReferenceProvider provider = new MyPsiReferenceProvider();
        registrar.registerReferenceProvider(StandardPatterns.instanceOf(StringLiteralExpression.class), provider);
    }
}
```

This is my test case:

```
package com.zenden2k.MyFrameworkIntegration.tests;

import com.intellij.patterns.ElementPattern;
import com.intellij.patterns.PlatformPatterns;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiElement;
import com.intellij.psi.PsiReference;
import com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.BasePlatformTestCase;

public class MyPsiReferenceContributorTest extends BasePlatformTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        myFixture.copyFileToProject("GetStaticDatasourceFixture.php");
        myFixture.copyFileToProject("user.xml");
    }

    protected String getTestDataPath() {
        return "src/test/com/zenden2k/MyFrameworkIntegration/tests/fixtures";
    }


    public void testThatStaticDatasourceReferenceIsProvided() {
        final ElementPattern<?> pattern = PlatformPatterns.psiElement().withName("test");
        myFixture.configureByText("user.php",
                        "<?php \n" +
                        "class MyClass extends CXMLObject {\n" +
                        "  public function test() {\n" +
                        "     $this->getStaticDatasource('t<caret>est');\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "}\n"
        );

        PsiElement psiElement = myFixture.getFile().findElementAt(myFixture.getCaretOffset());
        if (psiElement == null) {
            fail("Fail to find element in caret");
        }

        PsiElement parent = psiElement.getParent();
        final PsiReference[] ref = parent.getReferences();
        for (PsiReference reference : ref) {
            PsiElement element = reference.resolve();
            if (pattern.accepts(element)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        fail("Test failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - using Gradle is a recommended way for the development of the plugin. You may check the [Building Plugins with Gradle](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system.html) docs section for more details.

There is a [Simple Language Sample](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/tree/master/simple_language_plugin) project available in the [IntelliJ Platform SDK Code Samples](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples) repository that covers testing of the PSI References.